# Basic Authentication on Laravel from the third party API

Tags: laravel, rest, basic-authentication

I'm developing a web application right now. This application is using Laravel Framework and should get every data through another REST-API that already exists, also the informations about the authenticated user. This REST-API is using Basic Authentication as a method to confirm the authentication.

What I've made until now is this codes:

```
function userLogin(){

    //get username and password from login form
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //create a new Guzzle client
    $client = new Client();

    //send username and password to REST API to get the Authentication
    $response = $client->get('localhost:8080/api/user/login', [
        'auth' => [$username, $password]
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() < 200 || $response->getStatusCode() >= 300) {
        return back()->with('danger','Login failed.');
    }else{
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

I managed to log in but when I clicked the menu, it brought me back to Login page because middleware didn't know that the user logged in.

I also get an Angular Code from my co-worker that has managed the login attempt successfully in his Ionic Mobile Apps:

```
login(user:User): Observable<any> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders(user ?
  {authorization:'Basic ' + btoa(user.username + ":" + user.password)}
  :
  {});

  /**
   * a simple temporary measure to counter the error we get
   * when we log in to the app. 
   * because the API sends nothing as response, nothing is assigned to the currentUser variable.
   * this one line only assign value of currentUser manually to localStorage.
   * it consists only of username and password.
   */
  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));

  /**
   * as of now these do nothing, because the API sends out nothing as response.
   */
  return this.http.get<any>(API_URL + "login", {headers: headers})
  .pipe(map(response => {
    if(response){
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    return response;
  }));
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert it to PHP Codes or Laravel functions. I hope someone can give me solution for this problem.

Comment: "I managed to log in but when I clicked the menu" you are developing a rest api and clicking menus? with basic auth you should always send the headers.

Comment: What does your API give you in return to “logging in”? It must give you _something_ back, i.e. a token. Otherwise, how are you meant to prove who you are in other API requests?

Comment: I forget to mention that I didn't develop the REST API, it already exists and I try to consume the authentication from it in my web application. My co-worker said, I should save the headers in LocalStorage, but I haven't found the way to save a value in localStorage in the Laravel

Answer (score 0):

On backend to authenticate you have to apply middleware to authenticate user so for that you have to write code in Authenticate.php or any other custom middleware like this :

```
try{

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=".env("API_KEY");

        $request = $client->post($url, array(
            'form_params' => array(
                'idToken' => $token
            )
        ));
        //$response = $request->getBody();
        //$response = $request->send();
        $body = $request->getBody();

        if ($request->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            $res['status'] = 401;
            $res['message'] = 'Error, Invalid domain.';
            return response($res);
        }
    }
    catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
       log::info('catch========== Exception');
        $res['status'] = 401;
        $res['message'] = 'Error, Unauthorized.';
        return response($res);
    }
```